# ElasticSearch: Synchronization between replicas and primary shard

Tags: elasticsearch

I was going through the details about how updates to a document are propagated through the primary shard and sent to replica shards as provided here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_partial_updates_to_a_document.html

It is written that the updates to the document is communicated asynchronously to the replica shards and it tries till `retry_on_conflict` times to make sure that it is successfully executed.

Why does it have to try this this many times, it could have returned an error on the first try itself. Please provide some examples where the update would fail in the first case and would successfully take place after some tries.

Comment: You've read the documentation wrong. The `retry_on_conflict` is used to limit the number of updates attempts on the document, not on the replication to the replica shard(s).

Comment: @baudsp, I have read the documentation. 
From the documentation,
`Node 3 retrieves the document from the primary shard, changes the JSON in the _source field, and tries to reindex the document on the primary shard. If the document has already been changed by another process, it retries step 3 up to retry_on_conflict times, before giving up.`
Why does the update step tries this many times, instead of failing the first time?

Comment: There is more information on that mechanism [there](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/partial-updates.html#_updates_and_conflicts)